# Ionic Tabs not removing query parameters when navigating to other pages and back

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router

I have an ionic app with some tabs. I am navigating to one of the tabs using an a tag:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/tabs/home']" [queryParams]="{id: category.id}">
```

The above takes me to the a url like **'/tabs/home?id=2'**. However, when I click on the tabs and navigate to other tabs like profile or more, then I click on the home tab again it navigates me to **'/tabs/home?id=2'** instead of **'/tabs/home'**. I do not understand why the query parameter is still persisting and not removed. Any help would be appreciated.

tabs.html:

```
<ion-tabs class="footer-tabs" color="transparent">
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="home">
      <ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="profile">
      <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="more">
      <ion-icon name="list-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>More</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs-routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../home-tab/home.module').then((m) => m.HomePageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../profile-tab/profile.module').then((m) => m.ProfilePageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'more',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../more-tab/more.module').then((m) => m.MorePageModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a query param in the tab property so that it restarts when you press it.

See this:

[How to automatically add a query parameter when clicking an ion-tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68895030/how-to-automatically-add-a-query-parameter-when-clicking-an-ion-tab)

I hope help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Just added "?"

```
<a [routerLink]="['/tabs/home?']" [queryParams]="{id: category.id}">
```